# How to transfer BEP20 tokens from duplicate Safe created on Binance Smart Chain through safe-cli

Tags: transactions, wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis, gnosis-chain

I accidentally transferred some BEP20 tokens to my Ethereum safe address. To recover those funds, I contacted your support team, who advised us to create a duplicate safe on the BSC network. We followed their advice and successfully created a safe with the same address on the BSC network. However, I am still unable to see my funds through safe web UI. So, I checked the safe-cli option, which allows me to access my safe, but when I run balances command, it returns a zero balance. There are no commands for Blockchain opertion mode. Could someone please show me how to check the balance and transfer the BEP20 tokens to my BSC account address?

Comment: You can also use [BSCScan](https://bscscan.com/) to interact with contracts deployed on BSC.

Comment: And you can also interact with the Safe on the UI hosted by Gnosis at [gnosis-safe.io](https://gnosis-safe.io/).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I have added that safe to my gnosis web but not able to see my funds there that's why not able to interact.

Comment: Are you sure you have the network set to BSC?  My guess is that when you are checking your balance you are still checking on mainnet rather than BSC chain.

Comment: Yes I have set the network to BSC.